# Boxcar instant notifications

Tags: feature-request, notifications

I would like to have Boxcar support for Stackoverflow. This would make one less place I would need to go to on a day-to-day basis (and I usually end up forgetting!)

Comment: You might want to check [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/) to see if there already is something. One possibility for Mac OS X would be [Newt](http://stackapps.com/questions/1993/newt-question-answer-and-comment-and-rep-change-notifications-for-os-x), in combination with the Growl support Boxcar already has.

Comment: Hm, unfortunatly that wouldn't work as I don't have a Mac :')

Answer (score 3):

You might be barking up the wrong tree here. From their site:

> Don't see your favorite service here? [Contact us](http://boxcar.io/contact) and we'll get it added!